# Does the Laravel Query Builder need a different(ly named) Index than Eloquent for the same column?

Tags: mysql, indexing, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Do I need to have a *separate index* on the *same column*, one for raw queries via the **Laravel Query Builder** and one for **Eloquent**? Or is it sufficient to create only one index for the column?

I have following query via the Query Builder

`DB::table('offers')->where('engineer_id', '=', 1);`

And the same query via Eloquent:

`Offer::where('engineer_id', '=', 1);`

I currently have two indices on the DB column `engineer_id`.

1. `engineer_id` ( named like the column name for Facade queries, or Raw queries )
2. `offers_engineer_id_index` ( named automatically by Migration )

Thanks very much in advance for your answers :-)

Comment: You don't need different indices, just one is needed.

Comment: `<snide-remark>`Another case where the 3rd party software gets in the way of easily using MySQL?`</snide-remark>`